# Транзакция добавления элемента зачем возвращается объект и что с ним необходимо сделать?

Tags: c#, коллекции

Коллекция `ListCollectionView` при вызове метода `ListCollectionView.AddNew` возвращает объект, но, в документации сказано что

> Запускает транзакцию добавления и возвращает ожидающий новый элемент.

Что еще больше меня запутало, если он возвращает ожидающий объект, то присвоение нового объекта, по сути, должно затереть ссылку на ожидающий объект.

Как я это понял:

> Не трогать ожидаемый объект. При этом, если сделать каст добавляемого
>   объекта к типу `object` как сказано в документации, то объект будет
>   просто упакован в ожидаемый объект или это не так?

Все ли я правильно понял?

P.S. После такой транзакции, во вью у меня просто пустые объекты :) Как использовать эту транзакцию?

Вот что получилось с такого кода:

```
foreach (SerialPreviewViewModel serialPreviewViewModel in enumerable)
{
    object dataObject = Page.Serials.AddNew();
    dataObject = (object)serialPreviewViewModel;
    Page.Serials.CommitNew();
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (SerialPreviewViewModel serialPreviewViewModel in enumerable)
{
    SerialPreviewViewModel dataObject = (SerialPreviewViewModel)Page.Serials.AddNew();
    dataObject.Kingdom = serialPreviewViewModel.Kingdom;
    dataObject.A = serialPreviewViewModel.A;
    dataObject.B = serialPreviewViewModel.B;
    Page.Serials.CommitNew();
}
```

Comment: Аааа, вот оно как!